# gb4e: set font size

Tags: fontsize, linguistics, gb4e

The problem is simple. I use 14pt font size document-wide (`\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}`). But `gb4e` overrides this and uses (apparently) 12pt font in examples. How do I get `gb4e` to use the font size I want?

Comment: Can you please add a minimal document that shows the problem.  `article` class doesn't have a 14pt option, and `gb4e` does not override the global fontsize.